# Как увеличить объем выделяемой памяти программе на java?

Tags: java, jvm

Как увеличить объем выделяемой памяти программе на java

Answer (score 4):

Заходишь в java в панельке управления, открываешь вкладку "java", жмешь "view" и в графе "Runtime Parameters" вписываешь следущее:

`-XmsNm -XmxNm`, где `N` - количество оперативной памяти, которое ты желаешь выделить для java платформы. В первом случае ты указываешь минимальный порог, а во втором максимальный.

Пример:
`-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m` ,т.е, я желаю выделить на java 2 Гб оперативной памяти.

Comment: вроде бы все помогло спс большое