# Вопрос по finalize

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора

Добрый день, сразу к делу, у меня в приложении куча сцен и каждая сцена - это свой объект, там иерархия своя естественно создано и т.д. Чтобы отовсюду достучаться к этим объектам сделал отдельный класс, в котором хранится по одной ссылке на каждый объект, а ссылка на объект этого класса передаётся каждой сцене. Такое дело, что когда я перехожу к новой сцене, предыдущая мне уже ни к чему и я бы хотел, чтобы они не занимали место в памяти т.к. вместе со всеми полями они могут занимать его достаточно много. Тут я подумал про finalize(). Что если при совершении смены сцен, вызывать этот метод у сменяемой сцены, это поможет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

нет. Все объекты удаляет GC (сборщик мусора), вы можете только удалить ссылки на объекты, и оставить объект GC. Когда память заполниться до определенного предела GC все почистит сам.

---

Единственное, что могу вам посоветвать, это вызов System.gc() - этим вы попросите сборщика собрать недостижимые объекты.

Но если проблем в работе приложения нет, то не стоит их создавать. Не стоит пытаться управлять системными процессами JVM из своего кода, если на это нет необходимости.

Comment: А можно как-то задавать этот предел?

Comment: вы можете задать количество выделаемой память для JVM во время запуска атрибутами -XmsNm -XmxNm (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/68830/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java)

Comment: @ProstoCoder но единтсвенное, что произойдет это уменьшение оперативной памяти для работы. Если вы снизите порог для GC (я не знаю как это сделать и возможно ли), то он просто будет чаще запускаться и это может вызвать подтормаживания в работе приложения. Дополнил ответ единственным способом, который я знаю.

Comment: Короче в очередной раз с одной стороны скорость с другой стороны память